# Apache ActiveMQ - retrieving JMS metrics

Tags: spring, spring-boot, activemq-classic, prometheus

In my corporate project I am using Spring Boot and Apache ActiveMQ "Classic" 5.x Spring Boot starter. I am a totally beginner in this.

My goal is to expose Prometheus endpoint with some JMS queue metrics:

- number of messages in queue
- number of messages in error queue

What are dedicated tools for retrieving such metrics? Up to now I have found two possible ways. Can anyone confirm which of these two tools can solve my problem?

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.1.7.RELEASE/reference/html/#system-management-chapter
- https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/metrics.html (here the example is not very helpful)

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad

Comment: Looking at dependencies: activemq-all:5.16.0 and spring-boot-starter-activemq:2.0.9.RELEASE

Comment: I have to use ActiveMQ's. So both links are not applicable for my task?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the Spring stuff will work because that will provide Spring-related metrics from the application itself, not the ActiveMQ broker.

Also, the documentation for ActiveMQ you cited is for ActiveMQ Artemis. However, the dependency you're using is for ActiveMQ "Classic" 5.x. Therefore, the documentation is not applicable. However, if you choose to use ActiveMQ Artemis it is very simple to expose a Prometheus endpoint using this [Prometheus metrics plugin implementation](https://github.com/jbertram/artemis-prometheus-metrics-plugin). It's worth noting that Artemis is ActiveMQ's next generation message broker. If you're starting a new project I would recommend you use it rather than "Classic" 5.x. Artemis is planned to replace "Classic" and become ActiveMQ *next* in the future.

I think your best bet would be to configure the [Prometheus JMX exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter). It even has a [sample configuration](https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter/blob/master/example_configs/activemq.yml) for ActiveMQ "Classic" 5.x.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveMQ comes with [Jolokia](https://jolokia.org/) [bundled by default](https://activemq.apache.org/how-can-i-monitor-activemq) for extracting JMX Beans for the JVM, queues and a bunch of other metrics using HTTP. That way we can easily export using a software like [Telegraf](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf), which comes with a [simple input plugin for ActiveMQ](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/inputs/activemq) and a [simple output plugin for Prometheus](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/outputs/prometheus_client).